# Array.every returns false instead of true

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on something and I wrote this code that seems to return false instead of true:

```
function checkValidUsers(validUsers) 
{
    var validIds = validUsers.map(function (user) { return user.id; });

    return function (users) 
    {
        var ids = users.map(function (user) { return user.id; });
        return ids.every(function (id) { return id in validIds; } );
    }
}

var check = checkValidUsers([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);

check([{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);    // return false
```

The two map functions return the correct arrays ([1,2,3] for the first and [2,3] for the second), But every function does not for some reason.

Can anyone help me find the bug in the code?

Comment: operator _in_ check not value, but name property, you need use _indexOf_ instead

Comment: added the missing closing bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `in` to check whether an element in an array.

Instead , use `.indexOf` method.

```
return ids.every(function (id) { return validIds.indexOf(id) != -1; });
```

Comment: Strict equality can be used instead `!== -1`

Comment: @KyleK Here `!=` is safe because `. indexOf ` return number only.

Comment: Yep, it's a philosophy, I use always strict equality (faster to execute) except if I need to compare some values like "2" and 2.
@devnull, It's more probably a copy-paste error in the original post.

Comment: if _validIds_ is large - _indexOf_ can be not very fast :-)

Answer (score 1):

`in` can be used like this with coffeescript, but in JS, it's just a iterator operator. Try with:

```
return ids.every(function (id) { return ~validIds.indexOf(id); });
```

There are some missing/wrong characters in your code, here is a complete working code:

```
function checkValidUsers(validUsers) {
    var validIds = validUsers.map(function (user) { return user.id; });

    return function (users) {
        var ids = users.map(function (user) { return user.id; });
        return ids.every(function (id) { return ~validIds.indexOf(id); });
    };
}

var check = checkValidUsers([
    { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }
]);

check([{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use *in* you need a bit change you *validIds*

```
var validIds = validUsers.reduce(function (acc,user) {  
    acc[user.id]=true; 
    return acc; 
},{});
```

```js
function checkValidUsers(validUsers) {
    var validIds = validUsers.reduce(function (acc,user) {  acc[user.id]=true; return acc; },{});

    return function (users) {
        var ids = users.map(function (user) { return user.id; });
        return ids.every(function (id) { return id in validIds; });
    }
}

var check = checkValidUsers([
    { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = check([{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```